# first li of ul skipped when traversing nested uls with arrow keys using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, nav, accessible

I have a multi-level dropdown list that I want to make navigable with arrow keys using vanilla js. The first link of the first dropdown gets skipped as I key up the list. Because its parent li doesn't have a sibling, the traversal stops here. There must be some logical error but after a good deal of time, I can't see it.

I have tried referencing the button that should get focus after that link in many ways but with no success

I expected the traversal to go from Sub-Menu 3, to Sub-Menu 2 to Sub-Menu 1 to the Button next to Menu 2. Instead it goes from Sub-Menu 2 to the button, skipping Sub-Menu 1

```
<style>

ul.nav { display: flex; list-style: none; }

body:not(.js) ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999em;
}
body:not(.js) li.has-sub:hover > ul.sub,
body:not(.js) li.has-sub:focus-within > ul.sub,
body:not(.js) li.has-sub ul:hover {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}


body.js .hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999em;
}
.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999em;
}
body.js .visible {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
.visible {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav" id="main_nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    </li>

    <li class="has-sub">

        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <!-- <button class="trigger">More</button> -->      
        <ul class="sub">

            <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>

            <li class="has-sub">
                <a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
                <!-- <button class="trigger">More</button> -->
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Nested-Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Nested-Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Nested-Menu 3</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('js');

    //ADD BUTTONS
    let triggers = document.querySelectorAll('li.has-sub > a');
    for(var i=0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
        let toggler = document.createElement('button');
        toggler.setAttribute("class", "trigger");
        triggers[i].parentNode.insertBefore(toggler, triggers[i].parentNode.querySelector('ul.sub'));       
    }

    //HIDE SUBS BY DEFAULT
    let subs = document.querySelectorAll('ul.sub');
    for(let a = 0; a < subs.length; a++) {
        subs[a].classList.add('hidden');
    }

    //ADD TABINDEX -1
    var dropdownLinks = document.querySelectorAll('ul.sub a');
    dropdownLinks.forEach(dropdownLink => dropdownLink.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1"));

    var dropdownButtons = document.querySelectorAll('ul.sub button');
    dropdownButtons.forEach(dropdownButton => dropdownButton.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1"));

    //SHOW SUBS ON CLICK - DEFINE TOGGLE AND APPLY
    var toggle = function(elem) {
    //  elem.classList.toggle('visible');
        if(elem.classList.contains('hidden')) {
            elem.classList.remove('hidden');
            elem.classList.add('visible');
        } else if(elem.classList.contains('visible')) {
            elem.classList.remove('visible');
            elem.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    };

    var hide = function(elem) {
        if(elem.classList.contains('visible')) {
            elem.classList.remove('visible');
        }
        if(!elem.classList.contains('hidden')){
            elem.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    } 


    var buttonTogglers = document.querySelector('.nav').querySelectorAll('button.trigger');
    for(var f = 0; f < buttonTogglers.length; f++) {
        buttonTogglers[f].addEventListener("click", function(){
            toggle(this.nextElementSibling);
        });

        buttonTogglers[f].addEventListener("focusout", function(){
            //hides parent too which we don't want.

        });
    }   

    // var  = document.querySelector("ul.nav");
//  nav.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var subMamas = document.querySelectorAll('li.has-sub');

for(var g = 0; g < subMamas.length; g++) {  

        subMamas[g].addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

        var active = document.activeElement;
        active = '';
            if(e.keyCode === 40) {
                console.log('down');

                if(document.activeElement.nextElementSibling) {

                    if(document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('visible')) {
                        document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.focus();
                    } else {
                        document.activeElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.focus();
                    }           

                } else if (document.activeElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling){
                    document.activeElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.focus();
                }
                else {
                    document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.focus();
                }
            }


            //UP
            if(e.keyCode === 38) {
                console.log('up');

                var active;
                console.log('start' + document.activeElement.textContent );
                if(document.activeElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling) {
                    // console.log(active.parentElement.previousElementSibling);
                    active = document.activeElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild;
                    active.focus();
                    console.log('finish' + active.textContent);
                    active = '';
                } 
                else if(!document.activeElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling) {
                    console.log('no sib');
                    active = document.activeElement.closest('.sub').previousElementSibling;
                    active.focus();
                    active = '';
                }

            }   

            //RIGHT
            if(e.keyCode === 39) { 
                console.log('right');

            }
            //LEFT
            if(e.keyCode === 37) {
                console.log('left');

            }

        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are required to post your code here within your question and never a third party site: [mcve]

Comment: Thanks, Rob for the heads up; I've edited my question to include the code directly

Comment: is it possible to remove the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, adding the eventListener to the nav instead of each li.has-sub fixed the issue. i.e. removing:

```
var subMamas = document.querySelectorAll('li.has-sub');
for(var g = 0; g < subMamas.length; g++) {  
    subMamas[g].addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
```

and adding this instead:

```
var  = document.querySelector("ul.nav");
nav.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
```